# List not binding from JSON in POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, data-binding, asp.net-core-mvc

I have written a POST request that accepts my Model but once I get into the request the List is returning null.

I have read multiple solutions online from adding [FormBody] to checking my naming conventions but nothing seems to work correctly.

In my Script I create an Array `var UserPermissions = new Array();`

I then push to the array multiple objects:

```
var permission = {
    UserId: @Model.UserId,
    AppId: @Model.AppId,
    PermissionId: this.value
}
UserPermissions.push(permission);
```

Then I perform my Ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("UpdateUserPermissions")',
    data: JSON.stringify(UserPermissions),
    type: "post",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function (status) {
      swal("User Permissions have been updated.", { icon: "success" });
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      swal("Error updating permissions, please contact support.");
    }
});
```

My Controller POST Request Looks like this:

```
 public IActionResult UpdateUserPermissions([FromBody]PermissionPartialModel model)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

In every case `[FromBody]PermissionPartialModel model` is returning `null` when it should be returning a list.

Here is my Model:

```
 public class PermissionPartialModel
{
    public int AppId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public List<UserPermissionsModel> UserPermissions { get; set; }
}
```

What could be causing this and what is a solution to fix this?

Comment: Looks like you are passing an array, but trying to deserialize (FromBody) an object that has two properties and then an array.

Using a tool like Fiddler 4 can really help debug a problem like this.

Comment: You need to pass back an object (which will contain an array) - it will be in the format `{ AppId: xxx, UserId:, xxx, UserPermissions : [{ ... }, { ... }] }` to match your `PermissionPartialModel ` model. But we do not know what your `UserPermissionsModel` is so impossible to give an answer

Answer (score 0):

```
var UserPermissions= {
    UserId: @Model.UserId,
    AppId: @Model.AppId,
    PermissionId: this.value
}
//UserPermissions.push(permission);

$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("UpdateUserPermissions")',
    data: UserPermissions,
    type: "post",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function (status) {
      swal("User Permissions have been updated.", { icon: "success" });
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      swal("Error updating permissions, please contact support.");
    }
});
```

Comment: I am unable to approach this with a solution like yours because PermissionId can have many so it needs to be an array, then bind to a List.

Comment: you still can use it to array, `UserId: [1,2,3]`

Answer (score 0):

You are sending an array from view but receive object in controller. You need to change your parameter type from object to list

```
public IActionResult UpdateUserPermissions([FromBody]List<PermissionPartialModel> model)
{
   return View();
}
```

This will map but you will get `UserPermissions` null. To solve this you need to make changes in `PermissionPartialModel` and `permission` object in view.

**permission**

```
var permission = {
        UserId: 2,
        AppId: 2,
        UserPermissions: { PermissionId: 2 }
}
UserPermissions.push(permission);
```

**PermissionPartialModel**

```
 public class PermissionPartialModel
 {
        public int AppId { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public UserPermissionsModel UserPermissions { get; set; }

 }
```